# Where clause filter in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, stored-procedures, where-clause

I'm trying to create a procedure where it needs to filter the records with where condition by multiple scalar parameters. I'm facing the problem with the column  `I.[status]`.

In that column the values will be as "pending", "rejected", "submitted". But when the value comes with "All", I need to select all the status types (pending, rejected, submitted)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_cc_get_Invoices]   
    (@po_id         INT = NULL,  
     @sortBy        VARCHAR(50) = NULL,  
     @sortDirection VARCHAR(50) = 0,  
     @pageSize      INT = NULL,
     @page          INT = NULL,
     @TotalRows     INT = NULL OUTPUT,  
     @time_zone_offset INT = 0,  
     @vendor_id     VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
     @status        VARCHAR(20) = 'All',
     @invoice_id    INT = NULL,
     @invoice_from_dt DATETIME2 = NULL,
     @invoice_to_dt   DATETIME2 = NULL)  
AS  
BEGIN  
    SELECT 
        I.invoice_id, I.invoice_amount, I.[status],
        v.vendor_id, I.po_id, v.vendor_name,    
        I.netsuit_invoice_id, cd.currency_symbol
    FROM    
        invoice_details I   
    LEFT JOIN 
        vendor_details v ON v.vendor_id = I.vendor_id 
    LEFT JOIN 
        currency_details cd ON cd.currency_id = I.currency_id   
    WHERE 
        (@po_id IS NULL OR I.po_id = @po_id) 
        AND (@vendor_id IS NULL OR I.vendor_id = @vendor_id)  
        AND (@invoice_id IS NULL OR @invoice_id = '' OR I.invoice_id = @invoice_id) 
        AND (I.invoice_date BETWEEN @invoice_from_dt AND @invoice_to_dt)  
        AND I.[status] = @status
END
```

How to filter all the status records?

Comment: NULL is the default for your date parameters? And yet, using these defaults will produce an empty resultset. Vendor ID parm is varchar(max)? And you have not begun to address the obvious paging logic. Just start over - go search the internet for suggests about dynamic search conditions - start with [Erland's discussion](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html). Then search for techniques to address pagination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can express this with boolean logic.

Just change:

```
and I.[status] = @status
```

To:

```
and (@status = 'All' or I.[status] = @status)
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. But how it works ? Because there is no status "All"